# path and domain names missing in jsessionid cookie

Tags: spring, internet-explorer, tomcat, jboss, jsessionid

I have a `jsessionid` cookie set by Jboss/Tomcat container to track sessions.

Currently, my app behaves badly in the IE 8 browser. It's not showing the correct `DOMAIN` name or `PATH` name.

```
  NAME  JSESSIONID 
  VALUE  5CDFEE87C9B4C20ECA13FBB0DAS9RT 
  DOMAIN  .co.uk 
  PATH  / 
  EXPIRES  At the end of the Session
```

Actually `PATH` should be "/Test" and `DOMAIN` should be  "www.test.co.uk"

Can some one help me with `jsessionid` ?